# Finding the range of a function with two variables

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

I'm required to comment on the maximum and minimum values of the function :

$f(x,y)=2x^2+2xy+y^2-2x+2y+2$

*My question is, if both $x$ and $y$ are variables, how can I use standard methods to find the range on this function? Is there a trick here?*

*Also, how can we use differentiation in it(if we can)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: it is$$2x^2+2xy+y^2-2x+2y+2\geq -3$$ and the equal sign holds for $x=2,y=-3$
let $$f(x,y)=2x^2+2xy+y^2-2x+2y+2$$ and compute the partial derivatives
and solve the System
$$4x+2y-2=0$$
and
$$2x+2y+2=0$$

Comment: And what after we get the two equations?

Comment: you must solve this System for $x,y$ and then make the second derivative test

Answer (score 1):

The maximum does not exist.

Let $k$ is a minimal value.

Thus, $2x^2+2(y-1)x+y^2+2y+2-k\geq0$, which is quadratic inequality of $x$

with positive coefficient before $x^2$.

Thus, we need $\Delta\leq0$ or 
$$(y-1)^2-2y^2-4y-4+2k\leq0$$ or
$$y^2+6y+3-2k\geq0,$$
which is quadratic inequality again.

Thus, we need
$$3^2-(3-2k)\leq0$$ 
or $k\leq-3$ and from here $k=-3$ it's a maximal value of $k$ for which the inequality
$$2x^2+2xy+y^2-2x+2y+2\geq k$$
is true for all reals $x$ and $y$.

For $k=-3$ we obtain the equality case: $x=-\frac{2(y-1)}{2\cdot2}$ and $y=-3$.

Thus, $-3$ is a minimal value.

Done!

Since we know the answer already, we can write this solution by the following "nice" way.

For $x=2$ and $y=-3$ we get a value $-3$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$2x^2+2xy+y^2-2x+2y+2\geq-3$$ or
$$(2x+y-1)^2+(y+3)^2\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Comment: Cab you explain what did you do?

Comment: @user38227 I added something. See now please.

Comment: I think you need to explain that you are using the discriminant, for example, rather than just jumping from formula to formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to rewrite as a sum of squares looking to eliminate the "diagonal" terms and leave a constant

$$2x^2+2xy+y^2-2x+2y+2=$$$$=x^2+y^2+1+2xy+2x+2y+x^2-4x+4-3=$$$$=(x+y+1)^2+(x-2)^2-3$$